# How to add a field via logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I want to insert following field:

```
"date": {
"type": "date",
"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,SSS"
}
```

In my Logstash configuration I tried the following:

```
grok {
  patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"
  match => { "message" => "%{USERACTIVITY}" }
}
mutate {
  add_field => {
    "type" => "date" 
    "format" => "%{date}" 
  }
}

mutate {
  add_field => {
    "timestamp" => "{ %{type} , %{fomat} }"
  }
}
```

But it is not working. Is it possible to add a key value pair from exitsting?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
mutate {
  add_field => {
    "type" => "date" 
    "format" => "%{[date][format]}" 
  }
}
```